# Unary (Recursive) Relationship Mapping

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

[image]

How to map this kind of a relationship? The problem I'm having is according the ER shown abouve "Every Emplyee must have a supervisor" and "Every Employee must be supervised by an Employee". So when inserting the first record there there is problem because there is no other employees ID that I can insert as a supervisor. Since the both sides are mandatory it must have a both EmpID and SupvID when inserting a record. And SupervID cannot be null right?

Example Employee table:

Employee
EmpID | name | dob | SupervID

Comment: I think "reflexive" is better than "unary" in this context.

Answer (score 3):

ER modeling is supposed to reflect the business rules on the data.  The business rule that "every employee must be supervised by some employee" is impossible to implement, unless you allow one employee to supervise himself/herself or unless you allow loops in the supervision chain.

If your business rules are impossible, your ER model is going to reflect that fact.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your organization has a hierarchy, who supervises the supervisors? Who supervises the super-supervisors? Eventually, you will have at least one employee who does not have a supervisor. Thus, the business rules you have described are not realistic, and the database design will naturally be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a **`Many to 1` relationship**, the **Many** (Supervisee) side will bear their supervisor's ID. Therefore :

```
Employee (*ID*,supervisorID)
```